# How to set where clause only if the value is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

I have to write a query where the `where` clause should work on only if the field value is not empty else all record should be fetched.

I have a table name post

```
id    | valid_month | name |
------+-------------+------|
  1   | 1,2,3       | post1|
  2   | 1,2         | post2|
  3   |             | post3|
  4   | 2,5         | post4|
  5   |             | post5|
  ----+-------------+------+
```

I want query like

```
select * from post where IF(valid_month != "") THEN valid_month REGEXP '[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]' END IF;
```

and result should like

```
id    | valid_month | name |
------+-------------+------|
  1   | 1,2,3       | post1|
  3   |             | post3|
  5   |             | post5|
  ----+-------------+------+
```

Is there any way to get this output in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could gain this behavior with the logical `or` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   post
WHERE  valid_month = '' OR valid_month REGEXP '[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE` as well

```
SELECT *
FROM   post
WHERE (
       CASE WHEN IFNULL(valid_month,'') != '' THEN 
           valid_month REGEXP '[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]' 
       ELSE 1 = 1 
      END);
```